# Get client operating system name

Tags: servlets

I am trying to get the operating system name of a client in a servlet using the following code:

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)      throws ServletException, IOException {
  String userAgentString = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
  UserAgent userAgent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgentString);
  OperatingSystem os = userAgent.getOperatingSystem();
  }
}
```

I am getting an error UserAgent cannot be resolved to a type. How can i solve this?

Comment: did you load the necessary libraries?

Comment: I did add the jar folder available here https://github.com/haraldwalker/user-agent-utils